I could not verify Assertion Signature in Saml Response when I set -SamlResponseSignature "MessageAndAssertion"
I have an WebApplication which get information of user from ADFS by SAML protocol.
I can get information information of user from ADFS by SAML protocol.
BUT I saw a problem with signature verification.
I have a correctly certificate in WebApplication which I get from ADFS to verify signatures in SAML response.

When I configure in ADFS to sign AssertionOnly by running the command in Power Shell:
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "yyy" -SamlResponseSignature "AssertionOnly"

It means ADFS just sign Assertion
I can see signature in Assertion part
I can verify signature in Assertion part successfully

BUT when I configure in ADFS to sign MessageAndAssertion like that:
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "yyy" -SamlResponseSignature "MessageAndAssertion"

It means ADFS sign saml response and also sign Assertion in response
I can see signatures in saml response and also Assertion in response
I can verify signature in saml response part successfully
BUT I verify signature in Assertion, it failed.
Do you know which are possible reasons for this?
That is strange for me that I can verify successfully signature in Assertion when -SamlResponseSignature "AssertionOnly", but I verify fail signature in Assertion when -SamlResponseSignature "MessageAndAssertion".
Here is the code I used to verify signature:
 public static bool VerifySamlResponse(XmlDocument samlResponse, X509Certificate2 cert)
 {
     // Load the SAML response
     var signedXml = new SignedXml(samlResponse.DocumentElement);
     var signatureNode = samlResponse.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ds:Signature", GetNamespaceManager(samlResponse));
     if (signatureNode == null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Response signature not found.");
     }
     else
     {
         signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)signatureNode);

         //Verify the response signature
         if (!signedXml.CheckSignature(cert, true))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Response signature verification failed.");
             return false;
         }
         Console.WriteLine("Response signature verification succeeded.");
     }
     // Find the assertion
     var assertionNode = samlResponse.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("saml:Assertion", GetNamespaceManager(samlResponse));
     if (assertionNode == null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Assertion not found.");
     }
     else
     {
         // Log the assertion content
         Console.WriteLine($"Assertion Content: {assertionNode.OuterXml}");

         // Load the assertion signature
         var assertionSignedXml = new SignedXml((XmlElement)assertionNode);
         var assertionSignatureNode = assertionNode.SelectSingleNode("ds:Signature", GetNamespaceManager(samlResponse));
         if (assertionSignatureNode == null)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Assertion signature not found.");
             return false;
         }
         assertionSignedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)assertionSignatureNode);

         // Log the assertion signature content
         Console.WriteLine($"Assertion Signature Content: {assertionSignatureNode.OuterXml}");

         // Verify the assertion signature
         if (!assertionSignedXml.CheckSignature(cert, true))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Assertion signature verification failed.");
             return false;
         }
         Console.WriteLine("Assertion signature verification succeeded.");
     }

     return true;
 }

 public static XmlNamespaceManager GetNamespaceManager(XmlDocument doc)
 {
     var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
     nsmgr.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
     nsmgr.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
     return nsmgr;
 }

Thank you very much for your support.
Yours
Nghia
